# C++ destructor for object containing object containing pointer

Tags: c++, destructor

I could use some clarification on destructors.

I understand that if an object contains a pointer to allocated memory, then the object's destructor should call `delete` on that pointer. But what if an object contains an object that contains a pointer to allocated memory, such as a `string`?:

```
class Foo
{
    string bar;
};

Foo* foo = new Foo;
delete foo;
```

Is there aught I must do to ensure that the underlying `char[]` in the string is deallocated?

Comment: Could you modify the type to `Foo*` please? Stackoverflow won't let me do a 1 character correction ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string` type's destructor is responsible for cleaning up any resource it owns. Your object's destructor will call the destructors of member objects.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` class destructor is responsible for any cleanup. You don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

When your class is destructed, all its members - including the `string` - are also automatically destructed.

Cleaning up any internal resources held by the `string` (of which the char array is an implementation detail that no other class should rely on) is the `string` object's destructor's responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the rule as follow. Any object you create (and retain ownership of) with new must be destructed by calling `delete` in the destructor.